# Why won't quarto revealjs render image without text or fragment?

Tags: r, rstudio, quarto, reveal.js

I'm encountering a weird issue with Quarto where an image will not render unless I include text on the slide or wrap the image in a fragment.

Here are three sample `.qmd` slides that illustrate the issue.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: revealjs
---

## This slide works

text
![](image.png)

## This slide works too

:::{.fragment}
![](image.png)
:::

## This slide doesn't

![](image.png)
```

Why is this happening/how can I fix it? I would like to produce an image-only slide. Would my best option be to simply make it a background image or wrap it in a fragment?

Quarto version details:

```
> quarto::quarto_version()
[1] ‘1.3.361’
```

Comment: Which Quarto version are you using?

Comment: With Quarto version `1.3.354`, I am getting images in all three slides.

Comment: @shafee weird! I'm using `1.3.361`

Comment: Works for me, version 1.3.450.  HOWEVER, I'm here (at this page) because I'm observing the same behavior with a "naked" IMG tag. If I wrap it in <p><img ...></p> it shows. If I don't wrap it,  the rendering pipeline inserts a style="height:0; width:0" in the final html, effectively hiding the image. I'm using my own .scss file, so there is some odd interaction going on...

Answer (score 1):

See: https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/revealjs/advanced.html#stretch

I encountered the same problem with "naked" img tags. Modify your YAML header:

```html
format:
  revealjs:
    auto-stretch: false
```